# how format date to multiple fields in the model in the rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, model, input-mask

I have a form in rails that has a date field with input mask with format `mm/dd/yyyy`, but at the moment to save it, I am getting an error because of the format in the model is `dd/mm/yyyy`. I found a solution that maybe can work.

```
 def organization_date=(val)
   date = Date.strptime(val, “%m/%d/%Y”) if val.present?
   write_attribute(:organization_date, date)
 end
```

but I need one solution more elegant because I have more field of type date, and I can't do that for each field and updating the format to input mask to `dd/mm/yyyy` is not an option either because the client's requirement is that it be in the format `mm/dd/yyyy`

I am using Rails 6.0 beta

I'm grateful for any ideas that help solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the best way to fix it is, create a file in config/initializers/date_format.rb

```
module Typecasting
  module Date
    def cast_value v
      ::Date.strptime v, "%m/%d/%Y" rescue super
    end
  end

  ::ActiveRecord::Type::Date.prepend Date
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you can config active record default to this format but I suggest following solution. so you can format your date all around of application easily.

monkey patch Date class like this:

```
# config/initializers/date.rb

class Date
  def to_fd
    strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
  end
end
```

usage:

```
Date.today.to_fd
=> "05/28/2019"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `config/initializers/` create `date_format.rb`:

```
# Date
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:default] = "%m/%d/%Y"
```

Then restart the rails server..

Comment: I already tried to modify the Date:DATE_FORMATS[:default], but I get only good results on displaying dates but not at the moment of save it in the database with active record :(

Comment: Try this:  `Date::DATE_FORMATS[:db] = "%m-%d-%Y"`

Comment: If the above one also does not work, add `gem "chronic"` to your Gemfile and follow the steps: https://coreyward.svbtle.com/consistent-date-formatting-in-ruby-on-rails-5